# Qt, QML and C++: tips to increase compilation speed

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmake, ccache

I am a Qt developer. I have a very fast Ryzen 3900X and I'm looking for tips to speed up my daily work (faster builds in linux)

This is a sample project:

- full rebuild 24 cores: Elapsed time: 00:38.
- modify main.cpp: Elapsed time: 00:02.
- modify main.qml: Elapsed time: 00:05.

Now I am using these options which noticeably increase compilation speed (in project .pro):

```
unix{
   CONFIG+= use_gold_linker  # betterlink speed
   QMAKE_CXX = ccache $$QMAKE_CXX # use ccache. apt install ccache
   QMAKE_CC = ccache $$QMAKE_CC # use ccache
}
CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler # compile QML always (debug&release) (Qt>=5.11).QML debugging may not work
```

(You can use CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler or build always in release.)

And I get:

- full rebuild 24 cores: Elapsed time: 00:05.
- modify main.cpp: Elapsed time: 00:01.
- modify main.qml: Elapsed time: 00:01.

Now it's really very fast, and I can modify a QML file, build and execute  in just 1 second.

More ideas to increase compilation speed?

any ideas for better compilation times in windows + VS2019?
Qmake build system seems very slow in win32

any ideas for macos? (I haven't tried ccache and gold linker on mac os)